# Setting SSO for Grafana

Tags: single-sign-on, grafana

I have a web application which has a login page and it returns me lot of reports. To dashboard those data I am using Grafana.

I want to integrate a SSO between my app and grafana. When user logs in to my web application, he should be logged into grafana too. To do this I went through the [grafana documentation](http://docs.grafana.org/installation/configuration/). I didn't understand much. I tried with `google.auth` but is not right way for my requirement.

It should be possible to login using the credentials which are used to login to my web application. Any work around for this??

Comment: Can you add more context? What is your "issue"?

Comment: @NicoHaase    I have a web application  which has a login page and it returns me lot of reports . To dashboard those data I am using Grafana.  I want to integrate SSO between my app and grafana. When user login's to my web application he should be logged into grafana too. To do this I went through  [grafana](http://docs.grafana.org/installation/configuration/) documentation. I didn't understand much. I tried with google.auth but is not right way for my requirement. It should be possible to login using the credentials which are used to login to my web application. Any work around for this??

Comment: Please add such information to the question, not to the comment section

Comment: @NicoHaase Thanks do you have any work around for this??

Answer (score 1):

It's not very easy to achieve this but it's possible. As far as I know, Grafana is not yet supposed to work as SSO client out of the box. There is a workaround approach to expose it via proxy and to make Grafana trust whatever comes in from the proxy side: [Authproxy Docs](https://grafana.com/blog/2015/12/07/grafana-authproxy-have-it-your-way/)

On the other hand, you need to understand how SSO works. You'll need a server that will act as Identity Provider and your web apps will act as Service Providers (SSO Clients). You need to choose desired protocol, so far SAML2 and OIDC are very popular but there are others as well. I can recommend WSO2 Identity Server as it's free and open source, but maybe way too robust for your use case as well.

Considering the way how Authproxy concept in Grafana works, I would say the easiest would be to make workaround around workaround and to share session from your app to Grafana. From the architectural perspective it's not wise but considering the way you've asked this question, I would say you're missing a lot of knowledge about SSO in general.

Comment: Thanks for your replay.

Comment: I am able to configure single sign on between my application and grafana using Apache and Ldap

Comment: @mahadevgouda So could you share it as an answer step by step?

Answer (score 0):

You have to integrate your application and Grafana with a centralized OIDC IdP server using [OIDC authorization code flow](https://grafana.com/docs/auth/generic-oauth/).